# Rocket flying around earth at constant speed and constant altitude

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, aircraft

I am trying to make a rocket move around the earth at constant speed and constant altitude on a WGS84 earth within a python simulation (right now the output is a pandas dataframe). I start with the altitude, longitude, latitude, heading, and speed.

My method thus far has been to convert the heading and speed into a velocity in ENU coordinates. I then convert this ENU velocity to ECEF coordinates to propagate the rocket's path. The tricky part is getting the acceleration that changes the velocity while keeping the speed and altitude constant. Right now, I am getting this using centripetal acceleration. Within the centripetal acceleration, I use the gaussian radius of curvature of the earth at the current latitude of the rocket. I propagate the rocket using a for loop so I can recalculate the acceleration of the rocket at each point. I do this because the radius of curvature is changing with latitude.

However, my speed is decreasing and my altitude is increasing, so clearly something isn't working.

I have tested my unit conversions and double checked the kinematic formulae that I have implemented, and I think the only reasonable answer is that my acceleration is missing something. I can't quite figure out what it is though. I suspect that the issue revolves around what I am using for the turning radius. On a sphere, the answer is pretty simple: the turning radius is just the radius of the sphere. The elliptical Earth is much more complicated and I'm not sure what the turning radius should be in that coordinate system.

I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Along a heading, $\eta$, with $0=$ North, the radius of curvature is:

$$ R(\phi, \eta) = \Big(
\frac{\cos^2{\bar\eta}}{M(\bar\phi)}
\Big)^{-1} + \frac{\bar\sin^2{\bar\eta}}{N(\bar\phi)}
\Big)^{-1}$$

where the meridional radius of curvature is

$$ M(\phi) = \frac{(ab)^2}
{[(a\cos\bar\phi)^2 + (b\sin\bar\phi)^2]^{\frac 3 2}}
$$
and the normal radius of curvature is
$$ N(\phi) = \frac{a^2}
{[(a\cos\bar\phi)^2 + (b\sin\bar\phi)^2]^{\frac 1 2}}
$$

Of course $a$ and $b$ are semi major/minor axes of the ellipsoid, and for any angle like *coordinate*:

$$\bar\theta \equiv \frac{\pi}{180^{\circ}}\theta$$

and $\phi$ is the geodetic latitude (latitudes and longitudes are coordinates, not angles....don't express them in radians...convert them).

You didn't mention if you're working in a rotating reference frame with a *centrifugal* force and a Coriolis force, which is the way to go.

There really is no need to convert to ECEF, since ENU is Cartesian and easy to compute vector accelerations; moreover the conversion from ECEF to LLH, (lat, lon, alt), is not analytic...and has some pitfalls, though you may need the Jacobian between them. I have it somewhere.

Comment: I started using ECEF becuase Up deviates from altitude as soon as one leaves the origin of the reference frame. It seemed more straightforward to calculate the acceleration (and rest of the motion) in ECEF.

Currently, I am treating the reference frame as effectively non rotating (though ECEF is a rotating reference frame) with net acceleration v**2/r .

Using this as my radius seems to cause me to lose altitude and gain speed. Do you happen to know what direction this radius points in or how to calculate that vector. I imagine that would be the direction of acceleration.

Comment: V2/r is your problem. The centrifugal force does not depend on velocity. Moreover, with geodetic latitude and an ENU tangent frame, U should be up.

Comment: Should the sum of the forces in U be, F = lift + gravity +centrifgual = mv**2/r. Isn't that how one keeps the rocket turning along the Earth's surface?

Comment: lift is from wing. Thrust is from engines. Also drag, which you can ignore. You need Coriolis.  There is no mv2/r...it's just $F=ma$ Once you transform to a rotating frame, forget mv2/r.

Comment: Even if you are in a rotating frame like ECEF, don't you still need your net acceleration to be equal to v^2/r to move around the earth (like around the equator or around a meridian)? THe reason I am focused on ECEF rather than ENU is that ENU is built off of a tangent plane to the Earth's surface, so it isn't really aligned with altitude.

Are you saying that I should use a reference frame that rotates alongside the rocket?